# PHP: Copying file permissions with fileperms and ftp_chmod

Tags: php, permissions, ftp, file-permissions, chmod

The overall goal:
Copy the permissions of files from the local filesystem when uploading them over FTP using PHP.

The problem:
While ftp_chmod appears to succeed, and according to the print statement in the code I'm setting the right permissions, it sets completely wrong permissions.

The code:

```
<?php
    $perms = fileperms($src);
    if ($perms !== false) {
        // We only take the last 3 digits, since we're only interested in 'normal' file permissions, not extended ones.
        $perms &= 511;
        $permsm = sprintf('%o', $perms);
        print "DEBUG: Setting permissions: $perms :: ". decoct($perms) ." :: $permsm :: $dst\n";
        ftp_chmod($conn_id, $permsm, $dst);
    }
?>
```

The result:
Source / expected file permissions (local filesystem):

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 allen users  15572 Jun  2 12:40 Foo.docx
-rw-r--r-- 1 allen users  16877 Jun  2 12:40 Bar.docx
drwxr-xr-x 2 allen users   4096 Jun 15 14:01 configuration
drwxr-xr-x 9 allen users   4096 Jun 15 14:01 content
drwxr-xr-x 3 allen users   4096 Jun 15 14:01 local
-rw-r--r-- 1 allen users 152274 Jun 11 17:13 foo1.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 allen users   9984 Mar  2 10:44 footest.sql
drwxrwxrwx 2 allen users   4096 Jun 15 14:01 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 3 allen users   4096 Jun 15 14:01 versions
```

Destination / actual result file permissions (ftp upload):

```
--w----r-T 1 ftptest ftptest  15572 Jun 15 14:42 Foo.docx
--w----r-T 1 ftptest ftptest  16877 Jun 15 14:42 Bar.docx
d-wxrw--wt 2 ftptest ftptest   4096 Jun 15 14:42 configuration
d-wxrw--wt 9 ftptest ftptest   4096 Jun 15 14:42 content
d-wxrw--wt 3 ftptest ftptest   4096 Jun 15 14:42 local
--w----r-T 1 ftptest ftptest 152274 Jun 15 14:42 foo1.sql
--w----r-T 1 ftptest ftptest   9984 Jun 15 14:42 footest.sql
dr----x--t 2 ftptest ftptest   4096 Jun 15 14:42 tmp
d-wxrw--wt 3 ftptest ftptest   4096 Jun 15 14:42 versions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass $perms to ftp_chmod, not $permsm.

Comment: Thanks. That appears to make the code work as expected (I probably should've seen that, but I've been spending so long trying to make this code work I've lost sight through all the modifications I made).

I still don't fully understand why $permsm doesn't work tho - it seems to be a typing issue, but no amount of decoct/octdec cycles or prepending '0's seemed to be resolving the issue.

Comment: Say the permission is rw-r--r--, or 644. $perms now contains the octal number 0644, which is 420 decimal. $permsm contains "0644", which is not interpreted as octal but as the decimal number 644, while you want 420.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$perms &= 0511` instead of `$perms &= 511`. Permission masks are in octal notation, and the preceding 0 will make PHP interpret the number as octal.

Comment: As I already explained, the print statement shows the correct permissions, which leads me to doubt the problem is being caused at this point.

Changing this line causes the print statement to display incorrect permissions and does not fix the problem (permissions of uploaded files are still incorrect).